# Combobox DisplayMemberPath from list<object>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I am trying to bind a list to a ComboBox and use displaymemberpath to display the values.

This is my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxCommissieGroep" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Commissies}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="CommissieGroep">
```

ViewModel:

My ViewModel retreives a list of "Commissies"

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    commissies = new ObservableCollection<object>(await LoginBLL.GetCommissiesList());
}
```

Model:

```
public class InloggenBO : ObservableObject
{
    private int lidNummer;

    public int LidNummer
    {
        get => lidNummer;
        set
        {
            lidNummer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string commissieGroep;

    public string CommissieGroep
    {
        get => commissieGroep;
        set
        {
            commissieGroep = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string wachtwoord;

    public string Wachtwoord
    {
        get => wachtwoord;
        set
        {
            wachtwoord = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

My code database method:
The method creates a list of a dataset that has been retrieved from the database. That is why it is of type object and not InloggenBO

```
protected Task<List<object>> ExecuteReader(string SqlString)
{
    // Read to dataset
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn)
    {
        // Set commandtype
        CommandType = CommandType.Text
    }))
    {
        // Open connection
        conn.Open();
        // Fill dataset
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        // Close connection
        conn.Close();
    }

    return Task.FromResult(ToList(dataset));
}
```

Method that creates the list object

```
private List<object> ToList(DataSet dataSet)
{
    var list = new List<object>();

    foreach (var dataRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        list.Add(dataRow);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I have set my DataContext to the viewmodel and I know that the binding works because in my combobox without the displaymemberpath it says: "System.Data.Datarow". So what do I have to put in the displaymemberpath so that I can show its value?

Comment: Why is your ObservableCollection of type object when it should be of type InloggenBO presumably ?

Comment: Also in your XAML you're binding to Commissies but your vm you have a property (i assume) called commissies

Comment: @auburg I edited my question of how I retrieve my data, so that you know why I have an ObservableCollection of type Object

Comment: It seems like your `ToList(dataset)` returns a `List<DataRow>` - so why should a `DataRow` object know anything about your `InloggenBO` class?

Comment: Because you're binding to a plain object, there's no CommissieGroep property. You should be binding to a list of objects that have that property name for it to work.

Comment: @RandRandom Ohhh wait hold on you are right... but then it means that my ToList method is wrong. I added it in the question. I added the datarows to the list, because I couldn't add an dataset to it. Do I have to convert the dataset to an object and then create a list of it?

Comment: Yes - your observablecollection should be the appropriate type of instance the xaml is expecting.

Comment: Also, have a look at the vs debugging output for binding errors

Comment: As it is the simple fix is to bind to the defaultview of your datatable rather than an observablecollection. The displaymemberpath would then be the column name. But I think you should look into using entity framework and strongly typed data rather than ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding process which is done by the system is done in two parts. The first part is to a target object, and I mean *object* for its unknown to it, that object is supplied by the `DataContext` of the control.

If I control does not have a `DataContext` set, it inherits the parent control as specified in the XAML and if it is also null, that process repeats itself until ultimately the page's datacontext is taken.

Step 2 of binding is when that object is not null, it then reflects to the *property* from the binding *hint* given in the binding statement itself.

---

So in your case it is looking for a property named `Commissies` off the datacontext. If that property is not null and is a list, the combobox after a successful binding to a list then tries to find and show a property named `CommissieGroep` in each row to be shown.

Which in the case of the Combobox there are three things which have to be in line for a proper showing of data.

It appears that you do not have the right list (or observable list) of types expected to do a proper binding and showing of data; fixing that will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `ToList` method to this:

```
private List<InloggenBO> ToList(DataSet dataSet)
{
    //new list of InloggenBO instead of objects
    var list = new List<InloggenBO>();

    foreach (var dataRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        //create a new instance of InloggenBO
        var item = new InloggenBO();
        //this assumes that the column is named as the member
        item.CommissieGroep = dataRow["CommissieGroep"].ToString(); 
        //fill the other members

        //add the instane of InloggenBO to the list
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;
}
```

But, as @Andy mentioned you should consider using an ORM like Entity Framework.